# How I can to repeat a animation for buttons in a loop in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, repeat

I have a problem. 
I want to animate some buttons in a loop. It works it if the squence don't repeat, but I have a problem when the sequence repeat in the array.

```
- (void)flash:(id)sender delay:(int)time;
 {
     UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;     
     NSTimeInterval duration = 1;    
     [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                           delay:time + 0.5
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                      animations:^{
                          [button setAlpha:0.1f];
                      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                          [button setAlpha:1.0f]; 
                      }
      ];
 }
```

(this method works succesfully, where I call the method "flash")

```
- (void) play: (id)sender
{
    //buttons is a array that contains buttons => 
    //buttons = [right, left, up, down, nil]


    //positions is a sequence of the buttons positions
    //if buttons positions is [0,1,2,3]
    //positions have the random positions of buttons, example:
    //positions =  [0, 3, 4, 5,8, 7,9]


    int randomNumber;
    NSNumber *index; 

    randomNumber = (arc4random() % 4);
    [positions addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:randomNumber]];
    UIButton *btn;    

    for(int i=0; i<[positions count]; i++)
    {
        index = [positions objectAtIndex:i];
        btn = [buttons objectAtIndex:[index intValue]];
        [self flash:btn delay:i];        



    }

}
```

if the sequence of positions don't repeat, for example: positions= [1,2,3,0], the problem don't have problem.
But if the sequence is for example: positions = [0,0,0,1] (it repeats the numbers), the program don't show the animation.

Comment: I think this doesn't work, because you are canceling the first animation by immediately calling it agin when you try it with [0,0,0,1]. You should see buttons 0 and 1 each flash once.

Comment: @Andrés Zorrilla did you Checked The answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Method Will animate the View that you would pass to it.

```
-(void)flashingAnimation:(BOOL)boolVal forView:(UIView *) view{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | 
 UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     view.alpha = 0.0f;
                     view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x*0.75, view.frame.origin.y*0.75, view.frame.size.width*1.5, view.frame.size.height*1.5);
                 }   
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // Do nothing
                 }];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

And Finally call the above `method` by passing the `View` you want to `animate`.

`[self flashingAnimation:YES forView:Btn]`

**In Options add `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat`**

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because when you are calling `flash` and the button you are sending is the same as that which is already being animated the animation is interrupted (also if it has not really started yet due to the delay).

Try to refactor to keep track of the timing separately and use animations without delay. Maybe one solution is a completion block that calls itself recursively.